# FORM VALIDATION ISSUES

Tags: forms, validation

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="valid.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formValid.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <h2>Info Grabber</h2>
    <span class="required_fields">* Denotes Required Field</span> 
    <!--<form id = "contact_form" action="" >/-->
    <form id="contact_form" action = "#" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)" >
     <!--  <table> -->
     <div class="name">
        <div>
                    <label for='name'>Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' placeholder="First and last name" >

                    <div class="fixed" id="nameError">
                    Please enter your first and last name with a space between!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="address1">
        <div>
                    <label for='address1'>Address Line 1<span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type='text' name='address1' id='address1' >
                    <div class="fixed" id="address1error">

                     Please enter your address!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="address2">
        <div>
                    <label for='address2'>Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type='text' name='address2' id='address2'>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="county">County<span class="red">*</span></label>
         <select id="county" name="county">
              <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
              <option value="01">Andivim
              <option value="02">Armagh
              <option value="03">Carlow
              <option value="04">Cavan
              <option value="05">Clare
              <option value="06">Cork
              <option value="07">Derry
              <option value="08">Donegal
              <option value="09">Down
              <option value="10">Dublin
              <option value="11">Fermanagh
              <option value="12">Galway
              <option value="13">Kerry
              <option value="14">Kildare
              <option value="15">Kilkenny
              <option value="16">Laois
              <option value="17">Leidivim
              <option value="18">Limerick
              <option value="19">Longford
              <option value="20">Louth
              <option value="21">Mayo
              <option value="22">Meath
              <option value="23">Monaghan
              <option value="24">Offaly
              <option value="25">Roscommon
              <option value="26">Sligo
              <option value="27">Tipperary
              <option value="28">Tyrone
              <option value="29">Waterford
              <option value="30">Westmeath
              <option value="31">Wexford
              <option value="32">Wicklow
            </select>
          <div id="countyError" class="fixed">
          Please select your county!</div>
         </div>   
    </div>


        <div class="gender">
          <label>Gender<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="m">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="f" >Female
          <div id="genderError" class="fixed">
          Please select your gender! </div>
        </div>


        <div class="preferences">
          <label>Preferences<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="red" value="r">Red
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="green" value="g">Green
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="blue" value="b">Blue
          <div id="colorError" class="fixed">Please select a color! </div>
        </div>


        <div class="phone">
          <label for="phone">Phone<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Eg. 0871234567">
          <div id="phoneError" class="fixed">
         Please enter a valid phone number with 10 digits in length! </div>
        </div>


        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
          <div id="emailError" class="fixed">
         Please enter a valid email in the format "johndoe@domain.com"! </div>
        </div>


        <div class="password1">
          <label for="password1">Password (6-8 characters)<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1">
          <div id="password1Error" class="fixed">
          Please enter a valid password containing at least one uppercase letter and one number!</div>
        </div>


        <div class="password2">
          <label for="password2">Verify password<span class="red">*</span></label>
          <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
          <div id="password2Error" class="fixed">
         Passwords do not match, please re-enter! </div>
        </div>


        <div>
          <label>
          <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit">
           </label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>
            <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" id="reset">
          </label>
        </div>


   <!--   </table> -->
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>




</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm newish to javascript css and HTML. I have to create a form that changes the input borders to red and display an error message when the wrong data is entered.
I have to use javascript for the validation as part of project so I can't use HTML5 'required'. When I run my program none of the errors show and when i click the submit button it clears all the fields.

### I tried it in JSFiddle and got the following error which I don't understand

{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

I have tried and tried but I can't get this to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=====================================================================================

```
valid.css

    .red {    
    color: red;
}
.input.error {  /* for the error input text fields */
   border: 1px red inset;
   padding: 2px;
}
.error {
    visibility: visible;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*
table {
    border: 0;
}
td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 3px;
}
*/

label 
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px; 

}
.colorLabel {
    border: thin solid red;
}
.unColorLabel {
    border: thin solid #3FE916;
}
.fixed {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.required_fields {
    color: red;
}
```

======================================================================================

```
formValid.js


    function validateForm()
    {

var name = document.getElementById("name");
if(name.length < 5 || !name.match(/[A-Za-z ]$/))
{
    document.getElementById("name").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("nameError").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("name").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("nameError").className = "fixed";
}


var address1 = document.getElementById("address1");

if(address1.length === 0 || !address1.match(/[A-Za-z ]$/))
{
    document.getElementById("address1").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("address1Error").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("address1").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("address1Error").className = "fixed";
}


// Return true if correct element is selected

var county= document.getElementById("county");

if(county == "-1")
{
    document.getElementById("county").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("countyError").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("county").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("countyError").className = "fixed";
}



// Return true if the one of the radio buttons is checked


var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
   var isChecked = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < gender.length; i++)
    {
      if (gender[i].checked) 
      {
         isChecked = true;  // found one element checked
         document.getElementById("genderError").className = "fixed";
         break;
      }
      else
      {

    document.getElementById("genderError").className = "error";  
      }
    }

var color = document.getElementsByName("color");
   var isChecked2 = false;
   for (var j = 0; j < color.length; j++) 
   {
      if (color[j].checked) 
      {
         isChecked2 = true;  // found one element checked
         document.getElementById("colorError").className = "fixed";
         break;
      }
      else
      {

    document.getElementById("colorError").className = "error";  
      }
   }

var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
if(inputValue.length != 10 || (inputValue.search(/^[0-9]+$/) == -1))
{

    document.getElementById("phone").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("phoneError").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("phone").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("phoneError").className = "fixed";
}


var email = document.getElementById("email");
   var atPos = email.indexOf("@");
   var dotPos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
if((atPos < 1) && (dotPos < atPos + 1) && (inputValue.length < dotPos + 2))
{

    document.getElementById("email").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("emailError").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("email").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("emailError").className = "fixed";
}

var password1 = document.getElementById("password1");
var allowed = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}$/;  
var inputValue = password1.value.trim();
if(!(inputValue.value.match(allowed)))
{

    document.getElementById("password1").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("password1Error").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("password1").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("password1Error").className = "fixed";
}


var password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
if(password1.value != password2.value)
{

    document.getElementById("password2").className = "colorLabel";
    document.getElementById("password2Error").className = "error";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("password2").className = "unColorLabel";
    document.getElementById("password2Error").className = "fixed";
}

   }




enter code here
```

Comment: Even though you indicate it's not working, can you share your jsfiddle link?

Comment: This is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/fha9E/. I have changed the javascript but it's still not working

Comment: You have several problems with your HTML.  These are the ones I've spotted so far: 1) an extra ending script tag in the head, 2) a couple of TDs in your table that aren't in a table row, and 3) inconsistent select options (only one has an ending tag, though I think most browsers can interpret that ok).  I tried cleaning those up, but jsfiddle still complained about the HTML and JavaScript not validating.  Unless you're specifically needing to use JSFiddle for your assignment, maybe it would be better if you simply explained the original problem you have?

Comment: Hi Derek, I only used jsfiddle to validate javascript. I've changed the code a good bit now but I still can't get it to work. What I'm trying to do is when the wrong info is entered the border around that textarea will turn red and an error message will appear beside it in red until the correct info is entered.